# Scikit-learn pipeline TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to create a custom transformer for sklearn pipeline which will extract the average word length of a particular text and then apply standard scaler on it to standardize the dataset. I am passing a Series of texts to the pipeline.

```
class AverageWordLengthExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def average_word_length(self, text):
        return np.mean([len(word) for word in text.split( )])
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, x , y=None):
        return pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(x).apply(self.average_word_length))
```

then I created a pipeline like this.

```
pipeline = Pipeline(['text_length', AverageWordLengthExtractor(), 
                         'scale', StandardScaler()])
```

When I execute the fit_transform on this pipeline I am getting the error,

```
 File "custom_transformer.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "custom_transformer.py", line 43, in main
    'scale', StandardScaler()])
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._validate_steps()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 146, in _validate_steps
    names, estimators = zip(*self.steps)
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

Comment: Please provide the structure of the `Series` and the flow of execution.

Comment: @sentence, I am passing a pandas series, with one column, e.g.
message ( column name)
Weather update - a cold front from Cuba that could pass over Haiti
Is the Hurricane over or is it not over
Looking for someone but no name
UN reports Leogane 80-90 destroyed. Only Hospital St. Croix functioning. Needs supplies desperately.
says: west side of Haiti, rest of the country today and tonight
Information about the National Palace-
Please, we need tents and water. We are in Silo, Thank you!

>> right now, I am just trying to pass this to the pipeline which is not working.

Comment: @anidev711 do you need some additional help?

Comment: Yeah, @JanK your answer did help get rid of that problem, but now I am getting another error.
`File "custom_transformer.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "custom_transformer.py", line 43, in main
    'scale', StandardScaler())])
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._validate_steps()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 146, in _validate_steps
    names, estimators = zip(*self.steps)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @anidev711 If you think the new error is unrelated, consider creating a new question and marking this one as answered.

Comment: okay sure thanks for your help :) @JanK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Pipeline` constructor expects an argument `steps` which is a list of **tuples**.

Corrected version:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('text_length', AverageWordLengthExtractor()), 
                     ('scale', StandardScaler())])
```

More info in the official [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).